# Free Riordan Array transform software

Tags: combinatorics, math-software

Does anybody know of free/open software that can directly deal with Riodran Array transformations? I am trying to use them to analyze some combinatorial identities. I tried both reduce-algebra and Maxima and they can't even do the simple operations in a combinatorial sense. 
For instance $\frac{\partial^{n}\left(\left(1+x\right)^{m}\right)}{\partial x^{n}}$ is (more or less obviously) $\frac{m!}{\left(m-n\right)!}\left(1+x\right)^{m-n}$ or $ {\color{black}{\frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(-(n-1-m))}}}$ ; yet both packages fail this simple test.
I need this to evaluate/generate things like
$\left[t^{n}\right]\left(1+x\right)^{m}=\frac{m!}{\left(m-n\right)!n!}\left[t^{0}\right]\left(1+x\right)^{\left(m-n\right)}$
I don't mind a little programing but I want to handle automatically generated expressions like:
$\left[t^{k}\right]\frac{\left(t^{m}\right)}{\left(1-t\right)n}\left(1+z\cdot t\right)^{p}$
with *some* confidence; and without delving deep into the pattern recognition algorithms.
I did find that powerseries(exp,x,o) in maxima provides a combinatorial answer for the test case I mentioned; after some extraction and interpretation.  It doesn't handle more than one (1-x)^m term; but that's start.  For those who try it: the answer is a series in the Beta function; but that is just a different representation of the binomial function analyticaly extended.

Comment: Not sure how close this is to what you're asking for, but there is this: http://riordancalculator.com/

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Thanks for the link, :) It's not what I wanted, but I have bookmarked it.  It's not irrelevant but not symbolic.  I did find a breakdown; I might write/program it up.  It's interesting; in the end it's amenable to an _extensive_ rewrite process.  My phrase above "pattern recognition algorithms" was a mistake/miss-guess, but forgivable.  If somebody gripes, I will remove it.  If I do program it, I wonder if anybody here would be interested.